# iOS GCDAsyncSocket Error: Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=57

Tags: ios, swift, gcdasyncsocket

This is a weird one.  I'm using GCDAsyncSocket and when I'm using the iOS simulator sometimes I can connect and send, no problem but sometimes when I try to  connect and send something (writeData) I get the following error:

> **didDisconnect Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=57 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Socket is not connected"**

What is odd, I cannot predict when this will happen.  Also when I check to see isConnected, that returns true.

Here is the code (SWIFT):

```
    var sendBytes:[Byte] = [0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3] 
    var msgData = NSData(bytes: sendBytes, length: sendBytes.count)
    socket.writeData(msgData, withTimeout: -1.0, tag: 0)
    socket.readDataWithTimeout(-1.0, tag: 0)
```

The socket(didConnectToHost) callback fired with no issues and correct address and port returned, but when I try the above code to writeData to socket, I get the above error.

Any ideas why this would be happening randomly.

Comment: So it looks like it's an issue with the Simulator -- not 100% sure, yet. But, after a couple tests, if you leave the simulator open and then switch networks the issue happens.  Solution, restarting simulator if you switch networks (home vs work) seems to fix the issue.

Comment: This was driving me crazy. Your fix works for me too. Thank you!